# Trigger only updates on odd numbered input and not even

Tags: trigger, force.com, unit-test, opportunity, custom-field

```
trigger trig_Opportunity_CreateOppOwner on Opportunity (before update,before insert) {

List<id>OppsID = new List<id>(); //List that will hold all id of all new Opportunities owners

for(Opportunity Opp:Trigger.new){ //Loop that only retrives new versions of the Opportunity 
    if(trigger.isInsert)
        OppsId.add(Opp.ID);
    else if (trigger.oldMap.get(Opp.id).Op_Owner__c != trigger.oldMap.get(Opp.id).OwnerId)//trigger.isInsert and trigger.isUpdate added to account when it's null, avoids NullPointerException. Now all inserted opportunities are processed.           
        OppsId.add(Opp.ID);//adds all new opportunity owners to OppsId list. //Checks to see if they are new owners and not already on the owner list. 
}
if(OppsID.size() <= 100) 
List<Opportunity> oppsFromDb =  [SELECT id, OwnerId FROM Opportunity WHERE id IN:OppsID];   


for(Opportunity useOpps:oppsFromDb){                            
    trigger.newMap.get(useOpps.Id).Op_Owner__c = useOpps.OwnerId;
}
```

The following trigger basically checks to see if OwnerId has been updated. If it has, it stores the new Owner in a custom field called Opp_Owner__c. However, the trigger seems to change only on odd numbered changes. For example:

1. We change Owner. 
   Op_Owner__C gets updated with the new Owner
2. We change Owner again on the same opportunity.
   Op_Owner__c DOES NOT get updated with the second change on the owner we did.
3. We Change Owner a third time on the same Opportunity.
   Now the Op_Owner__c gets updated to the third owner change we did.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is the `Op_Owner__c` field in place just so that you can use it in formulas and whatnot? If so, [Summer '13 introduces cross-object owner fields](http://blogs.developerforce.com/developer-relations/2013/06/cross-object-owner-fields-a-powerful-new-formula-option.html) which may simplify your implementation.

Comment: Hi Mark, We actually just use Op_Owner__c as a way to keep track of all new Opportunity Owners that pop up. From my knowledge, we don't use it in new formulas yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to check against the Trigger.new Opportunity in your `else if`. That way, you're checking the current value of the `Opportunity.OwnerId` against the old `Op_Owner__c` field.

Here's the line I'd recommend changing:

```
else if(trigger.oldMap.get(Opp.id).Op_Owner__c != Opp.OwnerId) {
```

And, here's the full trigger:

```
trigger trig_Opportunity_CreateOppOwner on Opportunity(before update, before insert) {

  // List that will hold all id of all new Opportunities owners
  List <Id> OppsID = new List <Id> (); 

  // Loop that only retrives new versions of the Opportunity 
  for(Opportunity Opp : Trigger.new) { 
    if(trigger.isInsert) {
      OppsId.add(Opp.ID); 
    }
    // trigger.isInsert and trigger.isUpdate added to account when it's null, 
    //  avoids NullPointerException. Now all inserted opportunities are processed.    
    else if(trigger.oldMap.get(Opp.id).Op_Owner__c != Opp.OwnerId) { 
      // Adds all new opportunity owners to OppsId list. 
      //  Checks to see if they are new owners and not already on the owner list. 
      OppsId.add(Opp.ID); 
    }
  }

  if(OppsID.size() <= 100) {
    List <Opportunity> oppsFromDb 
      = [SELECT id, OwnerId FROM Opportunity WHERE id IN : OppsID];
  }

  for(Opportunity useOpps : oppsFromDb) {
    trigger.newMap.get(useOpps.Id).Op_Owner__c = useOpps.OwnerId;
  }
}
```

As pointed out, in the comments, the above code would only work for updates, not inserts due to IDs not being set until after insert.

Comment: Thanks Matthew, you were right, it was that line that needed to be changed. I tried out your solution too and it works.

Comment: Note that this trigger will not do anything on insert, only update. This is because records don't have Ids and are not queryable in before insert triggers. Your OppsId list will be full of nulls.

Answer (score 1):

This is a trigger I've needed several times, and can be done more simply than what you have there. Try this:

```
trigger trig_Opportunity_CreateOppOwner on Opportunity(before update, before insert) {

    for (Opportunity opp : Trigger.new) {
        opp.Op_Owner__c = opp.OwnerId;
    }
}
```